# How to check with reflection type of generic class

Tags: java, reflection

I have interface for implement Stack data structure:

```
public interface Stack<T> {
    void push(T element);
    //other methods
}
```

And one or more implementation where it's implemented.

Аnd I want to write a tester for this, where any of exemplar of this class may be tested. For example:

```
class StackImpl<T> implement Stack<T>{
//...
}
```

For call test i want write this:

```
Tester.<Integer>test(new StackImpl<Integer>());
```

And in tester this:

```
public static <T> void test(Object any) {
        if (any instanceof Stack) {
            testQueue((Stack<T>) any);
        }
    }

    private static<T> void testStack(Stack<T> stack) {
        new TestStack<>(stack).invoke();
    }
```

And test stack:

```
public class TestStack<T> implements Test {

    private Stack<T> stack;

    TestStack(Stack<T> stack) {
        this.stack = stack;
    }

    @Override
    public void invoke() {
        //and here need help!
    }
}
```

And in method `invoke()` i want get Original generic type, in this case is Integer.

How to get need value for implement test?

Comment: This is impossible due to type erasure, it would be possible if you would have separate class like `IntegerStack implements Stack<Integer>`

Answer (score 0):

The generic type of a variable is erased at runtime the only way you'd be able to do it is to specifically hold onto the type yourself i.e. add method to your stack interface for getting the type:

```
public interface Stack<T> {
    ...
    Class<T> getType();
    ...
}
```

Then in your impl add the type as a constructor arg:

```
public class StackImpl<T> implements Stack<T> {
    private final Class<T> type;

    public StackImpl(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

So now you'd have access to the type:

```
public class TestStack<T> implements Test {
    private Stack<T> stack;

    TestStack(Stack<T> stack) {
        this.stack = stack;
    }

    public void invoke() {
        System.out.println(stack.getType());
    }
}
```

And:

```
Tester.<Integer>test(new StackImpl<Integer>(Integer.class));
```

It's not ideal but it's the only approach that'd work!